# How can I ask a question that requires a very large data set?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to write a question asking why a data set composed of hundreds of csv files, which is 1.99 Gb on HD, becomes 3.8 Gb when loaded in memory (R). I can provide the full code (it's not much, basically a `read_list` function and a main which calls it), but how can I create a reproducible example?

I cannot share the original data on a shared drive for IP reasons, and I don't know how to generate a similar data set without wasting weeks. Each file has the same headers, but widely different number of rows (from 1 to thousands). Also, some columns which are empty in a file are not empty in another and vice versa. The reason why I want to ask this question is because I wonder if the excess memory usage is due to some mistake on my part in writing and using the `read_list` function.

Ps I specify that the language I'm using is R. I wrote it above, but probably it was too cryptic.

Comment: Sounds to me like you could be able to narrow it down to being strictly about memory usage rather than an entire difficult story about all these things you cannot or are not willing to do because they take time and effort. If you can keep the question to the point without it degrading into asking people to make wild guesses, it should be able to work.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem on a smaller scale at all? This would be the first thing to try - generate some CSV files with arbitrary content of random sizes, and then load them in using a similar function and see if you see the same behaviour.

Comment: @berry120 unfortunately not. When I create random files, the huge difference (nearly 100%) in size doesn't appear. There must be some characteristic of the files I have, which I'm missing when I generate the random files. Maybe I need to start from some of those files, and replace the content in them with random stuff.

Comment: @Gimby I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on a smaller scale. I surely don't want to waste people's time with wild guesses, but don't make it sound like I'm not willing to do things because "it takes time and effort". I'm more than willing to spend time and effort to create a good question and I've done that in the past. But to generate a fictitious > 1Gb data set, and making all the experiments necessary to reproduce the issue I'm having on my real data, would not just take "time and effort". It would take **a huge amount** of time and effort.

Comment: @DeltaIV That was going to be my next suggestion - keep the data in the same format, replace it with random values and see what happens.

Comment: This is not so much 'Help me writing a question' as 'help me devise a test mechanism'.  It does not belong on meta and, if you cannot share the problematic data, if does not belong on SO:(

Comment: "huge amount of time and effort" is considered the lowest acceptable  amount for SO question - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users :)...

Comment: It could be a variable type discrepancy... are you storing values as singles and reading as doubles (or similar)? Perhaps the random data you're reading is already in the same format when written by you. Try starting with just one of your csv files, does it produce the issue? How about 10? Try to narrow down the problem

Comment: @Wolfie thank you. Your comment and those from berry120 are useful. I'm working on them, and by next week I'm sure I'll have a good-to-go question.

Comment: @DeltaIV The brilliant thing about putting real effort into writing a good question is that you often solve your problem by doing some systematic debugging, and you end up not needing to ask!

Comment: Closely related: [How can I give a minimal example when my problem is with the size of the data?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323271) | [What is the best way to add your dataset to a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250975)

Answer (score 3):

Generally you'd need to come up with good MCVE including minimal data inline (real file data can be made publicly accessible on versioned storage in addition to inline sample) for question to  be useful for future visitors. General "how to debug" variant is indeed too broad and likely to be closed as such.

To your specific question - 2x memory usage is not unheard of and actually pretty decent multiplier... As alternative to providing actual code and data you can show your research in different ways. As an option come up with plausible [back of a envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation) calculation that explains why you believe number is wrong. If question would be in C/C#/Java I'd ask something like following:

> ...I have records that contain strings and 4-5 digit integers stored as UTF8 text which I read into matching structure. It feels like each row in memory should be roughly the same size as on disk - 4 bytes for integers, same size bytes for Utf8 strings in memory. Structure for each row is large so per-row overhead in collections can be ignored. I tried simpler structure with 10 integer values or 10 string values per row and it seem to match my calculations...

You'd still likely need to showing real (cleaned up) data row and how you store "row" in your program for someone to verify your estimates and suggest something.

Comment: what do you mean by versioned storage? Google Drive, DropBox? Or do you mean GitHub?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your "back-of-the-envelope" suggestion. If I include data on which the issue doesn't show up, the question will be closed or (rightfully) downvoted. In order to post the question, I need to find some data which is not my real data but on which the issue shows up. Do you agree? Re:  "You'd still likely need to showing how you [..] store "row" in your program", sure, I'll do that, no problem: I'll include the full code in my question, so this will be completely clear.

Comment: I'm glad that a 2x memory usage is not unheard of...then it might be that my code is just fine :-)

Comment: @DeltaIV I tried to suggest what type of "demonstrated research" may make question acceptable. Without your reasoning why do you think memory usage is off it is likely not possible to help... Usually questions like "My program uses CPU and memory, how to stop that" are rarely received well :).